# read expressjs request body in 4k chunks

Tags: node.js, express

I've got an ExpressJS endpoint that needs to take a request body and divide it into sequential 4k byte chunks or pages (aligned every 4k bytes) and do something different with each chunk.  Since this is binary data extra care would need to be taken so there isn't any interpretation as unicode or anything.

My first thought was something like this:

```
req.on("data", chunk => {
    // do something here
})
```

But the "do something here" would have to be, "take whatever size of data is in the chunk, process it in 4k increments, and retain whatever is left < 4k to append the next chunk to.   When I ran a test I saw that the first chunk received was just under 32k bytes, so indeed with every request I would have the overhead of shuffling bytes around so that I got 4k byte aligned chunks.

My second thought was to do something like this:

```
req.on("readable", () => {
    var chunk
    while (null !== (chunk = req.read(4096))) {
        // do something here
    }
})
```

In this case the "do something here" would be similar, but since I would only be reading 4k at a time I should theoretically have a bit less work to do.  In a test that I ran, I found that every read did return exactly 4k until the last read, which returned less than 4k.   It would be ideal if it always happened like this that I never had to deal with storing part of a 4k page to then append the remainder of the page, but I don't know of any guarantees that read() will always nicely provide this amount.

I'm not sure if I'm trying to re-invent the wheel here either, if there is a mechanism already in place to (asychronously) always pull off the next 4k without having to reassemble partial chunks.

What's the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate the data into a higher scoped buffer variable as `data` events arrive and when you have 4k or more, break out a 4k chunk and process it:

```
const dataSizeToProcess = 1024 * 4;    // 4k
let accumulatedData;

req.on('data', chunk => {
    // accumulate this chunk of data
    if (!accumulatedData) {
        // first chunk of data
        accumulatedData= chunk;         
    } else {
        // add this chunk to the existing buffer
        accumulatedData= Buffer.concat([accumulatedData, chunk]);
    }
    // process as many whole chunks as we have in the accumulatedData
    while (accumulatedData.length >= dataSizeToProcess) {
        // get a whole chunk into its own buffer from the start
        const piece = accumulatedData.slice(0, dataSizeToProcess);

        // make accumulatedData be the rest of the data
        accumulatedData = accumulatedData.slice(dataSizeToProcess);

        // now process the data in the piece buffer
        
    }
});

req.on('end', () => {
    // process the last bit of data in accumulatedData
});
```

Comment: I just went back and reading the documentation for "read" and I think maybe this is not necessary... `The optional size argument specifies a specific number of bytes to read. If size bytes are not available to be read, null will be returned unless the stream has ended, in which case all of the data remaining in the internal buffer will be returned.`  So I think that pretty much guarantees that it will work for my purposes.

Comment: @Michael - Yes, that other way should work too.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for "read" says:

> The optional size argument specifies a specific number of bytes to read. If size bytes are not available to be read, null will be returned unless the stream has ended, in which case all of the data remaining in the internal buffer will be returned.

This ensures that you will either read the entire 4k or, at the end of file you will read whatever is remaining.  So there is no need for anything more complicated.